# The trait bound `HttpResponse: _::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied the following other types implement trait `_::_serde::Serialize`:

Tags: rust, actix-web, rust-diesel

I'm working on a web application using actix-web and handlebars template engine. I'm trying to inject the database data to the template file but I'm facing lot of errors.

This my turple struct to collect database data:

```
#[derive(Serialize,Debug,Clone)]
struct IndexTemplateData(String, Vec<self::model::Book>);
```

And this is the function to fetch all data:

```
async fn index(
    hb: web::Data<Handlebars<'_>>,
    pool: web::Data<DbPool>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let connection = pool.get().expect("Can't get db connection pool");
    let books_data = web::block(move || books.limit(100).load::<Book>(&mut connection))
      .await
       .map_err(|_| HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish());
   // let books_data = books.limit(100).load::<Book>(&mut connection);
   

    let data = IndexTemplateData("Book Store".to_string(), **books_data**);

    let body = hb.render("index", &data).unwrap();

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body(body))

    // Ok(NamedFile::open("./static/index.html")?)
}
```

I highlighted the error with the error message:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `Vec<model::Book>`
     found enum `Result<Result<Vec<model::Book>, diesel::result::Error>, HttpResponse>`rustcE0308
```

This is the function to get data by it id:

```
async fn book(
    hb: web::Data<Handlebars<'_>>,
    pool: web::Data<DbPool>,
    book_id: web::Path<i32>,
) -> Result<HttpResponse, std::io::Error> {
    let mut connection = pool.get().expect("Can't get db connection from pool");
    let book_data = web::block(move || {
        books
            .filter(id.eq(book_id.into_inner()))
            .first::<Book>(&mut connection)
    })
    .await
    .map_err(|_| HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish());

    let body = hb.render("book", **&book_data**).unwrap();
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().body(body))
}
```

this is the error message:

```
the trait bound `HttpResponse: _::_serde::Serialize` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `_::_serde::Serialize`:
  &'a T
  &'a mut T
  ()
  (T0, T1)
  (T0, T1, T2)
  (T0, T1, T2, T3)
  (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
  (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
```

Have try different method to solve this but not getting it right

I've tried to store the data inside a vec and try to expose it to the template file through turple rust.

Answer (score 0):

Your `books_data` is wrapped in two extra `Result`s.

For the first error you could pass forward the `Result`s:

```rust
let books_data = web::block(move || books.limit(100).load::<Book>(&mut connection))
    .await
    .map_err(|_| HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish())??;
```

which only works if `Error` implements `From<diesel::result::Error>` and `From<HttpResponse>` you can use `.unwrap()` instead of `?` for a quick fix but should convert the error down the line.

The other error seems to be very similar and can probably also be resolved by forwarding the error with `?` or `.unwrap()`ing.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but doesn't work. How do I implement from for both error and response? Thanks